# Beautiful Soup. How to get a link containing a specific word?

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-2.x

HTML contains strings in divs:

- 'div class="slide"' 'img src="xttps://site.com/files/r_1000,kljg894/43k5j/35h43jkl.jpg' '/div'
- 'div class="slide"' 'img src="xttps://site.com/files/r_2000,kljg894/43k5j/35h43jkl.jpg' '/div'
- 'div class="slide"' 'img src="xttps://site.com/files/r_3000,kljg894/43k5j/35h43jkl.jpg' '/div'

Need to get a link containing only "r_3000"

This code gets all the links:

```py
imglink = soup.find_all('img')
print(imglink)
```

I looked through and tried many tips. For example:

`('img', string="*r_3000*")`,  `('img', string=re.compile('r_3000')` and `('img', string=lambda s: 'r_3000' in s)` and many others, but all this does not work :(

Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways you can do that.Try css selector.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<div class="slide"><img src="xttps://site.com/files/r_1000,kljg894/43k5j/35h43jkl.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"> <img src="xttps://site.com/files/r_2000,kljg894/43k5j/35h43jkl.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="xttps://site.com/files/r_3000,kljg894/43k5j/35h43jkl.jpg"></div>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
for item in soup.select("img[src*='r_3000']"):
    print(item['src'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first over-select from the document and do your filtering with Python. For example:

```
img_links = soup.find_all('img', src=True)
r_3000_links = [ l['src'] for l in img_links if 'r_3000' in l['src'] ]
```

will return a list of all links that contain `'r_3000'`